# When printing linked list value at 0 index it gives segmentation fault.

Tags: c

// my main function

```
int main (void) {
srandom(1);
SLL *p = newSLL(displayINTEGER,freeINTEGER);
insertSLL(p,0,newINTEGER(3));
insertSLL(p,sizeSLL(p),newINTEGER(2));
insertSLL(p,1,newINTEGER(22));

int x = getINTEGER((INTEGER *) getSLL(p,2)); //Works fine it prints 2
printf ("x is : %d\n",x); 

x = getINTEGER((INTEGER *) getSLL(p,1)); //Works fine it prints 22
printf ("x is : %d\n",x);

x = getINTEGER((INTEGER *) getSLL(p,0)); //This is where i get error (Segmentation Fault)
printf ("x is : %d\n",x);
```

//Insert function @param SLL, index, value

```
 void insertSLL(SLL *items,int index,void *value)
    {
    SLL *newSLL = malloc(sizeof(SLL));
    newSLL->value = value;
    if (items == NULL)
            {
            }
    else if (index == 0)
            {
            newSLL->tail = items;
            items = newSLL;
            }
    else
            {
            struct sll *current = items;
            for(int i=0; i<index-1; i++)
            {
            current = current -> tail;
            }
            newSLL -> tail = current -> tail;
            current -> tail = newSLL;
            }
    }
```

//getSLL @param SLL and index and returns pointer to that value.
 //this function works fine with index > 0 but gives segmentation fault when index == 0

```
    void *getSLL(SLL *items,int index)
    {
    int count = 0;
    while (items != NULL)
    {
            if (count == index)
            {
            return items->value;
            }
    count++;
    items = items->tail;
    }
    return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: well, maybe that the function returns `NULL` and you're dereferencing a null pointer. Your debugger could help you

Comment: **Or** you could help us by providing us with [mcve]?

Comment: Btw C is pass by value ...so `items = newSLL;` is not doing what you are expecting

Comment: so how should i rewrite that? items -> value = newSLL->value; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First element is never inserted because C is pass by value. So you make changes to the local variable of that `insert..()` function.

You should either pass the address of the pointer or return the address of the allocated memory and assign it to the pointer.

And then again, one thing to notice is - you already allocated memory dynamically before you even called `insertSLL` - you don't need that.  The `insert` logic can be written in way that it would do that itself for the first and middle nodes both.